# Local Area Connection missing

Tags: windows-7

I have an ASUS laptop and i have windows seven installed .
in "Network And Sharing Center" , The "Local Area Connection"  is missing .
it was there before . 
also the"change adapter setting" or "network connections" folder is empty.

can anybody please help me?

by the way is there any other way to get to "local area connection properties" ?

Comment: Which ASUS laptop do you have? Be sure to install the network adapter drivers, that should get Windows to detect the LAN adapter.

Comment: thanks i fixed it myself . i wanted to answer the question but the web site wouldn't let me cause i don't have enough credit.

Comment: ^^ You should edit the question and add the solution there itself.